# How to store pointer to function template which takes Callable object as one of its parameters

Tags: c++, c++14

Consider following example:

```
template <typename T>
void f (T t) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}


template <typename T>
struct F { 
    static constexpr void (*m) (T) = &f; 
};
```

and usage:

```
F<int>::m (10);
```

So far, so good. Problem shows up when I want to store pointer to function template which takes for example an lambda expression. Consider this one:

```
template <typename T, typename C>
void g (T t, C c) {
    std::cout << c (t) << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename C>
struct G { 
    static constexpr void (*m) (T, C) = &g; 
};
```

and usage:

```
auto l = [] (auto v) { return v; };
G<int, decltype (l)>::m (20, l);
```

When compiling on GCC 5.3.1 with:

```
g++-5 -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror=return-type main.cpp -o main
```

I got:

```
‘constexpr void (* const G<int, main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)> >::m)(int, main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)>)’, declared using local type ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
```

**Why this happens?**

**Is there any way I can achieve this code to work?**

One possible solution that I am not interested in:

```
struct O { 
    template <typename T>
    T operator() (T v) {
        return v;
    }   
};
```

with usage:

```
G<int, O>::m (20, O {});
```

Comment: What about using `std::function`?

Comment: What I really want to achieve is to have a function (all this code that I presented is implementation detail and not shown to the user) which takes a predicate, which most of the time should be filled with lambda expression.

Comment: `std::function` works well with lambda expressions, that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: @ArturPyszczuk: "*One possible solution that I am not interested in:*" But that's exactly what a lambda *is*.

Comment: @NicolBolas I meant that I do not want to write Callable object this way. I really want to use lambda instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error, if you remove some stuff, says:

> [...] `m` [...] is used but never defined [-fpermissive]

So just follow the compiler's orders, and define it:

```
template <class T, class C>
constexpr void (*G<T,C>::m)(T,C);
```

And now it works. This is because in C++14, you are required to add a definition for static constexpr data members, from [[class.static.data]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.static.data#3):

> The [static data] member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.

---

This is no longer necessary in C++17 for `constexpr` static data members, as a result of [p0386](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf). The text [now reads](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.data#3.sentence-4):

> If the [static data] member is declared with the `constexpr` specifier, it **may be** redeclared in namespace scope with no initializer (this usage is deprecated; see [depr.static_constexpr]).

Comment: @PasserBy Cheers! Thanks

Comment: Is it really odr-used? As far as I can see, `m` can be used in a prvalue constant expression, and its value is immediately read by the accessing expression. IIRC, those are the main conditions to prevent an odr-used, and they are both met.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'm super confused by the definition of odr-used, but from what I can tell, since `m` appears in a function call expression, and a function call expression is not listed in the set of potential results of some expression *e* , `m` is odr-used.

Comment: @PasserBy the variable `m` appears as an expression `G<int, decltype (l)>::m` and applying the lvalue to rvalue conversion on `m` will produce a constant expression (because it's a constexpr variable with a preceeding initialization), and `G<int, decltype (l)>::m` is an element of the potential results of an expression `e` on which the lrvalue to rvalue conversion is directly applied: `e` is `G<int, decltype (l)>::m` itself, whose potential result is itself.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That makes perfect sense. I don't know what's happening here.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'm asking a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872465/is-a-function-pointer-odr-used-if-it-is-called), might be overkill but I'm personally really confused