# Is a function pointer odr-used if it is called

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This question is sparked by a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44740285/4832499)

Consider the following code

```
template <typename T, typename C>
void g(T, C) {}

template <typename T, typename C>
struct G
{ 
    static constexpr void (*m) (T, C) = &g; 
}; 

void foo()
{
    auto l = [](int){return 42;};
    G<int, decltype(l)>::m(420, l);
}
```

This is legal in C++17 everywhere, `G::m` is defined within `G` via inlined variables and all that.

What's weird is in C++14 and C++11 gcc rejects this stating `m` is used but never defined, while clang accepts it. [Live](https://godbolt.org/g/usczjq)

Is `m` odr-used? Or is this a gcc bug?

Comment: Once you have an intuitive understanding of the "potential results" definition, I think the whole thing is easier to parse. In this example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d0ad6728ecc394b , `B::a` is not odr-used by the `return` statement, because an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `B::a` produces a prvalue constant expression, and it's part of the potential results of `B::a.x`, and an lvalue to rvalue conversion is applied to `B::a.x`. So, I think of "potential results" as meaning "decoupled-from by an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I thought member access can never result in the odr-use of the object whose member is being accessed? Namely `B::a.x` can never result in `B::a` being odr-used?

Comment: sure it can. `const int &x = B::a.x` will odr-use `B::a` because no lvalue to rvalue conversion is applied to `B::a.x` nor on any other expression with `B::a` as a potential result element.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Again, that makes perfect sense. I think my last remaining issue is whether gcc is aware of this or not.

Comment: BTW note also that GCC 7.1 and GCC 8 upstream accepts the code. Again, it looks like a bug of GCC already fixed in newer versions, for you are not odr-using `m`.

Comment: Moreover, note that it just works with any other type that isn't the one of a closure. This is another clue that GCC is doing something wrong here. If you sum it with the fact that your are not odr-using `m`, newer versions accept the code as any other compiler does and the standard seems (I'm not a language lawyer) to agree, well... You have your response. ;-)

Comment: [ODR violation is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#4.sentence-1) A conforming compiler can choose not to emit any warning or error.

Comment: @cpplearner I am aware. But the problem is that (suspected) valid code is rejected

Comment: @cpplearner Diagnostic isn't required in case of multiple definitions in different translation units (well, actually that's impossible, unless you are the linker). That's what your link says. I don't think the part _no diagnostic required_ applies to all ODR violations in general.

Comment: My understanding is that the set of potential results of a function call expression is always empty, so based on "A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression ex is odr-used by ex unless [...] and, if x is an object, ex is an element of the set of potential results of an expression e, [...]." the function pointer in the function call expression should always be odr-used.

Comment: I might add it also compiles fine with MSVC with /std:c++14 or later. I highly suspect its a bug in gcc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TLDR `m` isn't odr-used, this is indeed a GCC bug.

### odr-use

Intuitively, variables needs to be stored in memory somewhere. The only exception is when the value of the variable can be optimized out by the compiler and never used in another way. Odr-usage formalizes this idea: a variable requires a definition only if it is odr-used.

Odr-usage is defined by [[basic.def.odr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#4)

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is odr-used by `ex` unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` yields a constant expression that does not invoke any non-trivial functions and, if `x` is an object, `ex` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion  is applied to `e`, or `e` is a discarded-value expression.

In other words, `x` isn't odr-used if either

1. `x` doesn't appear as a potentially-evaluated expression (e.g. `decltype(x)`).
2. `x` isn't an object (e.g. a reference) and applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` yields a constant expression.
3. `x` is an object and applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` yields a constant expression. Furthermore, there is a "coupled" expression `e` that either has the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to it or is discarded.

The "coupling" refers to the intuition that there is some enclosing expression closely related to `x` that can only be used in certain ways without needing `x` be stored in memory. This notion is formalized by the definition of potential results [[basic.def.odr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#2)

> The set of potential results of an expression `e` is defined as follows:
>
> - If `e` is an id-expression, the set contains only e.
> - If `e` is a subscripting operation with an array operand, the set contains the potential results of that operand.
> - If `e` is a class member access expression, the set contains the potential results of the object expression.
> - If `e` is a pointer-to-member expression whose second operand is a constant expression, the set contains the potential results of the object expression.
> - If `e` has the form `(e1)`, the set contains the potential results of `e1`.
> - If `e` is a glvalue conditional expression, the set is the union of the sets of potential results of the second and third operands.
> - If `e` is a comma expression, the set contains the potential results of the right operand.
> - Otherwise, the set is empty.

An expression `ex` that is within the potential results of `e` is "coupled" with `e`.

### The question

Applying the definitions

1. `m` is potentially evaluated.
2. Applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `m` yields a constant expression.
3. `m` is an object.
4. `m` is an expression whose potential results includes `m` and has the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to.

We thus conclude `m` isn't odr-used.

Comment: And what about pointers to the data segment? If you have `const char * ptr = "asd"`, would printing of such a variable results in odr-usage and why?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a GCC bug. This is a interpretation of the c++14.

> One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable
>   that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire
>   program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). The
>   compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior
>   of the program that violates it is undefined.

The error is

```
source:7:29: error: 'constexpr void (* const G<int,
foo()::<lambda(int)> >::m)(int, foo()::<lambda(int)>)', declared using
local type 'foo()::<lambda(int)>', is used but never defined
[-fpermissive]
```

And it is true that the type `foo()::<lambda(int)>` **is never defined (by the programmer, it is actually defined by the compiler)** since every lambda has a unique type.

replacing line `static constexpr void (*m) (T, C) = &g;`  by `static inline constexpr void (*m) (T, C) = &g;` makes the error go away.

Which is clearly an indication that **m is odr-used if not tag as inline**.

I believe this message is a way of warning you that

```
auto l = [](int){return 42;};
G<int, decltype(l)>::m(420, l);
G<int, decltype(l)>::m(420, [](int){return 42;});
```

will result in the following error (even with using -std=c++1z and GCC or CLANG)

```
source: In function 'void foo()': <source>:15:34: error: could not
convert 'g' from 'foo()::<lambda(int)>' to 'foo()::<lambda(int)>'
     G<int, decltype(l)>::m(420, g);
```

because the lambda types are unique.

However GCC transforms the error into a warning if you use `-fpermissive` which is really a way of knowing that it is not a GCC bug but an over-protection meant to discourage certain practices.

One way of lifting any ambiguity without using -fpermissive is to do what GCC recommends and declare the prototype.

```
template <typename T, typename C>
void g(T, C) {}

template <typename T, typename C>
struct G
{ 
    static constexpr void (*m) (T, C) = &g; 
}; 
typedef int (*return_int)(int);
void foo()
{
    auto l = [](int){return 42;};
    G<int, return_int>::m(420, l);
    G<int, return_int>::m(420, [](int){return 41;});
    //Or even better if the aim is to use embedded template parameters
    return_int ln = [](int){return 42;};
    G<int, decltype(ln)>::m(420, ln);
}
```

This compile fines.

Last, why did the GCC team make this protection pop with C++17. I don't know maybe they receive complaints that the behavior was over protective and that cast errors of lambda types were sufficient. But seriously the error

```
error: could not
    convert 'g' from 'foo()::<lambda(int)>' to 'foo()::<lambda(int)>'
```

Is a little bit off-putting the first time… When getting this error your mind wonders, until you come to the conclusion that `decltype([](int){return 42;})` is different from `decltype([](int){return 42;})` ! When you try this...

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    auto l = [](int) {return 42; };
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(l)).name() << std::endl;
    auto m = [](int) {return 42; };
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(m)).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs (under visual studio)

```
class <lambda_37799c61f9e31cc7b5f51a1bd0a09621>
class <lambda_818eb0a43a553fc43d3adadd7480d71e>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't address the question. odr-usage concerns whether `m` needs to be defined in the first place. GCC thinks `m` is odr-used, which is the subject of question.

Comment: You mentioned is the error a GCC bug I am giving m'y two cents and saying it is a question of interpretation and certainly not a bug.

Comment: The error is caused by the compiler thinking `m` is odr-used but not defined. The question asks whether `m` is odr-used. Your answer said it is indeed not defined. The (potential) bug in the compiler isn't with whether `m` is defined or not: it isn't in C++14.

Comment: You have your answer. 'm is odr-used but not defined' in c++14. Were it not odr-used we would not have problem with the definition. Don't you think ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to add info about the behavior when adding inline.